# Is requesting HTTP faster than HTTPS when there is a heavy traffic on the website?

Tags: http, https, web

So at next Tuesday, 9:00 AM, we're going to have an online war at our college website; literally.

It's about course registration. There are few excellent courses with limited capacity, and a lot of students will be trying to register for them. So at 9:00:00 AM when the website opens registration section, the race begins, and we know by experience that if you want one of those high-demand courses, 9:00:30 is already too late.

I'm not exchanging any secret data with the website that is, security is not a concern. The Q is, since the website opens in HTTPS by default, does using HTTP give me advantage as no one is using it? Does this make sense? I think superusers here may have already tried this so any experience?

Comment: That would heavily depend on the server and what they setup. Usually a HTTPS connection needs some more preparation time and computation power to setup. But depending on how they did set it up you might not gain an advantage by using HTTP. In addition the site might not working if you're just using HTTP (again dependent on the setup).

Comment: I believe that it works fine on HTTP (tested some parts of the site). However I can't figure out more about the network setup.

Comment: I answered you question regarding [HTTP vs HTTPS](http://superuser.com/a/1170947/566983) differences, but in your case, when you'll experience the **heavy load** and **peak will be really short** – I'd rather be thinking about **optimization of content generation** time and **caching mechanisms** on the server side. HTTPS vs HTTP protocols will not be a deal breaking, so don't think of it.

Comment: You really need to have a talk with whoever came up with the requirements and explain to them why they need to change. HTTP vs HTTPS isn't the issue here. The issue is that they need to come up with a fair way to decide to who gets the course spots. You will have users who get a bad experience on your website, and there is no *technical* solution which will prevent it. Only a change of the requirements can help.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you'll **not** notice any significant difference between HTTP and HTTPS response rates. But a lot of things are dependent on your server setup, and where you host it.

Of course, there will be some level of overhead due to encryption in case of SSL, but it is highly dependent on your: hardware, server software, ratio of dynamic vs static content, client distance to server, typical session length, etc.

Servers that are heavy on dynamic content tend to be impacted less by HTTPS because the time spent encrypting (SSL-overhead) is **insignificant** compared to content generation time.

SSL handshaking is the major cost of HTTPS. The initial SSL handshake incurs substantial latency, the mechanisms used to maintain the session add only negligible latency. As a result, unless your sessions are short, you get more [performance benefit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Resumed_TLS_handshake) from the compression than you lose from the session maintenance.  So that's why "typical session length" and "caching behavior of clients" are important.

You can easily test the difference between HTTP and HTTPS performance in your own browser using the **[HTTP vs HTTPS Test](http://www.httpvshttps.com/)** website by [AnthumChris](https://twitter.com/AnthumChris):

> This page measures its load time over unsecure HTTP and encrypted
>   HTTPS connections. Both pages load 360 unique, non-cached images (2.04
>   MB total).

__

In your case, apparently, there will be a peak traffic and high hit-rate during the **short period of time**... so https vs http is not a deal breaking question for you, you should rather think of these:

- optimization of content generation time;
- introducing caching mechanisms;
- using CDN as much as possible for static contents.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between HTTP and HTTPS is a few milliseconds - HTTP is one round trip time, while HTTPS may have multiple round trip time due to [SSL handshakes](https://www.incapsula.com/cdn-guide/cdn-and-ssl-tls.html#ssl-handshake). Perhaps consider a CDN to accelerate those milliseconds rather than resorting to more insecure application delivery by disabling SSL/TLS.

I would add that security should still be a concern - you may have malicious bots trying to bring down your site, any number of attacks whether by students or simply outside actors, and if something goes down during site registration that is going to be far worse than students being locked out of overenrolled courses.

Comment: The extra roundtrips actually won't actually matter in the described scenario, since users can open the connections a few seconds before they need them. That will save at least one roundtrip and remove the difference between HTTP and HTTPS.